# How to modify python code to move converted files to a separate folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have python  code that converts multiple .xlsx files to .csv. But it puts them into the same folder. 
How to modify this code to make sure it puts .csv files to a separate folder?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
excel_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/username/Documents/TestFolder/JanuaryDataSentToResourcePro/*.xlsx') # assume the path
for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel, 'ResourceProDailyDataset') # if the sheet name is always the same.
    df.to_csv(out)
```

Comment: This question is vague. Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I simply want to move converted file to a separate folder. Not to keep converted csv file in the same folder with excel files.

Comment: add a folder name in the path before the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the directory from your file name and then give your `out` a new directory :

```
for excel in excel_files:
    folder = r'C:\ASeparateFolder\'
    out = folder + excel.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel, 'ResourceProDailyDataset') # if the sheet name is always the same.
    df.to_csv(out)
```

Note I used `'\\'` to split, it seems to be the common splitting point for `glob` whether you use `'\'` or `'/'` for your initial excel_file directory.

Comment: Thank you. It works if I i use :

`folder = r'C:/Users/username/Documents/TestFolder/CSVFolder/'`

Answer (score 1):

First split the path, remove the folder that you don't want and replace it with some other folder.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
excel_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/username/Documents/TestFolder/JanuaryDataSentToResourcePro/*.xlsx') # assume the path
# folder name for the converted csv files
different_folder = "csv_folder"
for excel in excel_files:
    # make a csv path
    csv_folder_path =  "\\".join(excel.split('\\')[:-1])+"\\"+different_folder+"\\"
    if not os.path.exists(csv_folder_path):
        # create it if it doesn't exist
        os.makedirs(csv_folder_path)
    # full path of the csv file
    out = csv_folder_path+excel.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel, 'ResourceProDailyDataset') # if the sheet name is always the same.
    df.to_csv(out)
```

This will create a new folder csv_folder in all the folders that have Excel file in them and the converted csv files would be placed in this folder.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the variable that controls your output file. Try something like this

```
out = 'some_directory/' + excel.split('.')[0]+ '.csv'
```

The directory will have to exist for this to work.